# Может ли HttpFileCollection[key] вернуть null?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

На сервер отправляются файлы на основе которых формируется отчет. Для создания отчета **необходимо минимум 3 и максимум 5 файлов**.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostFiles()
{
    HttpFileCollection httpFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

    var streams = new List<Stream>();

    var countAddedStream = 0;            
    foreach (var formDataKey in httpFileCollection.AllKeys)
    {
        var httpPostedFile = httpFileCollection[formDataKey];
        if (httpPostedFile != null)                
            streams.Add(httpPostedFile.InputStream);                             
        if (++countAddedStream == 5)
            break;                                    
    }

    // Fail
    if (countAddedStream < 3)            
        return BadRequest("Не достаточно корректных файлов для создания отчета");
    // Success
    //...
    return Ok();
}
```

**1) Интересует: правильно ли я делаю валидацию и извлекаю содержимое согласно моему условию и практике хорошего дизайна?** К сожалению, что-то типа `LINQ` для `HttpFileCollection` я не смог обнаружить, чтобы сделать что-то вроде`.Where(x => x[key] != null && x[key].InputStream != null)`.

**2)** Также интересует: действительно ли `httpFileCollection[formDataKey]` может вернуть `null`. Я делаю валидацию в этом месте `if (httpPostedFile != null)` т.к. ReSharper намекнул на это. А к примеру, когда я через Postman попытался добавить запись в form-data, указав только key, то такая запись просто не добавилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частичный ответ:
`httpFileCollection[]` надо привести к ожидаемому типу с помощью `.Cast<T>()` или отфильтровать `.OfType<T>()`, например
`httpFileCollection.Cast<HttpPostedFile>().Where(hpf => ...)`.

Именно `.Where(x => x[key] != null && x[key].InputStream != null)` не получиться, т.к. у вас не перечисление экземпляров `httpFileCollection` (у которых есть доступ по индексу и ключи), а внутри класса определены массивы ключей и файлов, [см.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpFileCollection.cs,4d13c1c9cf06c3ed)

```
public sealed class HttpFileCollection : NameObjectCollectionBase {
        // cached All[] arrays
        private HttpPostedFile[] _all;
        private String[] _allKeys;
        ...
```

т.е. будет вроде `.Where(hpf => (hpf != null)&&(hpf.InputStream != null))`

Comment: Т.е., если капнуть глубже, правильно ли я понимаю, что метод `httpFileCollection.Cast<HttpPostedFile>()`будет приводить каждый объект, который ему будет приходит из  [NameObjectCollectionBase.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/nameobjectcollectionbase.cs,80d0316befb424f2)?

Comment: @adamshakhabov ["Элементы объекта HttpFileCollection имеют тип HttpPostedFile"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx), т.е., как я понимаю, приведение/фильтр будет выполняться над `HttpPostedFile[] _all;`; проще наверное фильтр `.OfType<T>()`, хотя бы формально.

Comment: А вот эта проверка `hpf.InputStream != null` не лишняя? Мне кажется в коллекции такого элемента так и так просто не будет. Или все-таки можно отправить в запросе файлы с `null` значением?

Comment: @adamshakhabov тут я просто исходил от вашего `.Where(x => ...)`, когда хотелось _что-то_ _вроде_  :)  КМК, проверять или нет все объекты на не-NULL перед использованием определяется исключительно здравым смыслом.